# Why do I get this message when I run npm install

Tags: laravel-8, npm-install

-npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

4 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Answer (score -1):

Try using this command:

$ npm set audit false